# Apply CSS styling to left and right arrows for this div slide?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got this little project I'm hoping to add to my website. It's a simple div slider with arrows. So far, I've coded up to this extent, and I need help to include two key features to this slider:

------------------------------ *Two features I'm trying to achieve* ------------------------------

**Feature One:** I want to apply some sort of CSS styling to this slider, telling the user that *they have reached the end of the slider*. That is, *if a user **clicks left** to the last item, **disable or change style of the left arrow.*** Likewise, *if a user **clicks right** to the last item, **disable or change style of the right arrow.***

**Feature Two:** You will notice that currently, there are eight div slides in the slider. Now, try commenting four of the slides. Clicking any arrow naturally wouldn't work *as 4 slides is the maximum limit.*
*I want both arrows to be disabled when the div slides are **less than or equal to 4.***

```js
let buttonLeft = document.getElementById('slide_left')
let buttonRight = document.getElementById('slide_right')

let container = document.getElementById('slider')

buttonLeft.addEventListener('click', function() {
  container.scrollLeft -= 90
})

buttonRight.addEventListener('click', function() {
  container.scrollLeft += 90
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #555;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
}

div#slide_wrapper {
  width: 440px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: fit-content;
}

div#slider {
  width: 350px;
  display: flex;
  height: fit-content;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.thumbnail {
  min-width: 80px;
  min-height: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

div.thumbnail:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: darkturquoise;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: goldenrod;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: powderblue;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: firebrick;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(6) {
  background-color: sienna;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(7) {
  background-color: bisque;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(8) {
  background-color: navy;
}

div#slide_wrapper>button {
  height: fit-content;
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 800;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

div#slide_wrapper>button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="slide_wrapper">
  <button id="slide_left" class="slide_arrow">&#10094;</button>
  <div id="slider">
    <div class="thumbnail active">1</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">2</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">3</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">4</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">5</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">6</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">7</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">8</div>
  </div>
  <button id="slide_right" class="slide_arrow">&#10095;</button>
</div>
```

Please help me solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the above answer works, you might also be able to do this with the [scrollWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollWidth) property.

Using the [steps to determine whether the element is fully scrolled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight#determine_if_an_element_has_been_totally_scrolled) and using the widths instead of heights, you can apply CSS classes to the buttons based on the thresholds you set.

I might update the answer to include a code example when I get home, but I think the docs will help you out a lot.

**Update:**

As stated, I made a version which disables the buttons according to the scrolling- and clientWidth.
The advantage of this is that there is no need to keep track of the amount of thumbnails, and will always work as long as you add **same-sized** thumbnails to your slide.

Besides changing the JS file, I added `.deactivated` to your css file, and assigned this class to the left button in the html file.

Hope this helps!

**Update 2:**
Fixed the issue mentioned in the comment by Matrion.

```js
let buttonLeft = document.getElementById("slide_left");
let buttonRight = document.getElementById("slide_right");

let container = document.getElementById("slider");

// Initial calculation of how much their is to scroll, if none, disable
// both buttons since every thumbnail fits in the view.
let scrollingLeft =
  container.scrollWidth - container.clientWidth - container.scrollLeft;

if (scrollingLeft === 0) {
  buttonLeft.classList.add("deactivated");
  buttonRight.classList.add("deactivated");
} else {
  buttonLeft.addEventListener("click", function() {
    container.scrollLeft -= 90;
    if (container.scrollLeft === 0) {
      buttonLeft.classList.add("deactivated");
      buttonRight.classList.remove("deactivated");
    } else {
      buttonLeft.classList.remove("deactivated");
      buttonRight.classList.remove("deactivated");
    }
  });

  buttonRight.addEventListener("click", function() {
    container.scrollLeft += 90;
    let scrollingLeft =
      container.scrollWidth - container.clientWidth - container.scrollLeft;
    if (scrollingLeft === 0) {
      buttonRight.classList.add("deactivated");
      buttonLeft.classList.remove("deactivated");
    } else {
      buttonRight.classList.remove("deactivated");
      buttonLeft.classList.remove("deactivated");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #555;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  font-family: "Helvetica";
}

div#slide_wrapper {
  width: 440px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: fit-content;
}

div#slider {
  width: 350px;
  display: flex;
  height: fit-content;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.thumbnail {
  min-width: 80px;
  min-height: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

div.thumbnail:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: darkturquoise;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: goldenrod;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: powderblue;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: firebrick;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(6) {
  background-color: sienna;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(7) {
  background-color: bisque;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(8) {
  background-color: navy;
}

div#slide_wrapper>button {
  height: fit-content;
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 800;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

div#slide_wrapper>button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.deactivated {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="slide_wrapper">
  <button id="slide_left" class="slide_arrow deactivated">&#10094;</button>
  <div id="slider">
    <div class="thumbnail active">1</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">2</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">3</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">4</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">5</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">6</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">7</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">8</div>
  </div>
  <button id="slide_right" class="slide_arrow">&#10095;</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Please answer let's compare. Thank you!

Comment: Your code (JavaScript specifically), seemingly rivals, in a subtle way, the preceding answer. This is really a 96.2% correct answer. Try commenting the thumbnails to 4 or 3, when you click the left or right arrow, it becomes active again. None of the arrows should be active when it is less than or equal to 4 thumbnails.

Comment: Your answer is a bit more straightforward than the preceding answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Matrion I have edited the post to fix that issue. Thank you for mentioning it!

Comment: It is still not working

Comment: Just edited it, should function now @Matrion!

Comment: Okay, let me break it down this way. In the HTML, comment the div slides till you are left with 3 or 4 slides. You will notice that the arrow is still active.

Comment: When a maximum of 4 slides are available, the arrows should not be active. Even when you click on them. Get it? Just check it out.

Comment: @Matrion The code has been fixed, you might want to check out my codepen for it: https://codepen.io/impaex/pen/qBxvWWd

The codepen (as well as the answer now) has the code as you want it.

Comment: Seen what I'm talking about?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245676/discussion-between-matrion-and-impaex).

Answer (score 2):

I just added a fe JS lines to do the tasks for you. If the end of oen slide is reached a class to the button is added to change the `visibility` to `hidden`. You can change the CSS settings as you deem fit or apply other changes directly through JS however you like. This example is just to show you how you could do it:

At start I added a few variables:
`slidesAmount` => The number of your total slides. EDIT: Is now calculated by the script so you do not have tos et it manually
`slidesPerScreen` => How many slides are dispalyed at the same time on screen
`currentSlideCounter` => The slide numebr that is display at the very left
`maxSlideCounter` => is a calculated variable to mark the end of the possible slides to the right.

Then I added to your functiosn an `if`-statement to raise or lower the counter `currentSledeCounter` to keep it updated. The `if`-statement ensures that you dont lwoer or raise that counter when you reached that specific end.

Last but not least I added a function with a `switch`-statement that applies a class to the button when an end has reached or removes the classes when not end is reached yet.

EDIT: I added an `eventLister` onload to run the script at the start so that by default the left arrow is hidden.

EDIT 2: There was a bug that occured because of the `switch-statement` logic if there is just one more `slideAmount` then the `slidesPerScreen`. So I remoevd the switch statement and simpliefied the logic. It now removes all class by start and adds the class if a certain end has reached:

```js
/* eventListener to run the script at the start and hdie left button automatically */
window.addEventListener("load", change);


var slidesAmount = document.querySelectorAll('#slider .thumbnail').length,
    slidesPerScreen = 4;
var currentSlideCounter = 1;
var maxSlideCounter = slidesAmount - slidesPerScreen + 1;


let buttonLeft = document.getElementById('slide_left')
let buttonRight = document.getElementById('slide_right')

let container = document.getElementById('slider')

buttonLeft.addEventListener('click', function() {
  container.scrollLeft -= 90;
  if (currentSlideCounter > 1) {
    currentSlideCounter -= 1;
  }
  change();
})

buttonRight.addEventListener('click', function() {
  container.scrollLeft += 90;
  if (currentSlideCounter < maxSlideCounter) {
    currentSlideCounter += 1;
  }
  change();
})

function change() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.slide_arrow').forEach(el => el.classList.remove('changes'));
  if (currentSlideCounter == 1) {
    document.querySelector('#slide_left').classList.add('changes'); 
  }
  if (currentSlideCounter == maxSlideCounter) {
    document.querySelector('#slide_right').classList.add('changes'); 
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #555;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; /* justify-items is incorrect, it's justify-content */
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
}

div#slide_wrapper {
  width: 440px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: fit-content;
}

div#slider {
  width: 350px;
  display: flex;
  height: fit-content;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.thumbnail {
  min-width: 80px;
  min-height: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

div.thumbnail:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: darkturquoise;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: goldenrod;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: powderblue;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: firebrick;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(6) {
  background-color: sienna;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(7) {
  background-color: bisque;
}

div.thumbnail:nth-child(8) {
  background-color: navy;
}

div#slide_wrapper>button {
  height: fit-content;
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 800;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

div#slide_wrapper>button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* this CSS line applies changes with the JS script */
button.changes {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="slide_wrapper">
  <button id="slide_left" class="slide_arrow">&#10094;</button>
  <div id="slider">
    <div class="thumbnail active">1</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">2</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">3</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">4</div> 
    <div class="thumbnail">5</div>    
    <div class="thumbnail">6</div>
    <div class="thumbnail">7</div> 
    <div class="thumbnail">8</div>
  </div>
  <button id="slide_right" class="slide_arrow">&#10095;</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This is awesome. Just when I was about to leap for joy I noticed 2 things: Comment four divs, then click "left", notice that it turns red, please sir, help me fix this. Finally, by default, I think since the slide begins at 1 let the left arrow be red. Thank you so much I'm grateful.

Comment: Okay, now comment 4 div slides. The buttons should disable when divs are less than or equal to 4. You are truly amazing. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: yeah I was onto that meanwhile and fixed that aswell in the `change()` function. Check if you need an explaination for that added or understand that without it.

Comment: Have you tried commenting four divs? :(

Comment: If there are no more than four slides. Let both buttons disable.